# Need to use JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE type of JDialog in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, awt, jdialog

I had used `JDialog` box to display an Error message ,

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
        null, "ErrorMsg", "Failure", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

but the condition is the message box should always be on the **foreground** so that the user is bound to proceed and doesn't misses it.

Hence i used a **`JFrame` instead and used `setAlwaysOnTop(true)`**
to display the message.i used `JLabel` and `JButton` and
I made it appear as `JDialog` by the help of the below link

[How do I remove the maximize and minimize buttons from a JFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665355/need-to-remove-maximize-and-minimize-buttons-from-jframe-to-reduce-width-further)

I want to add a Error message symbol in the above frame as we get when we use `JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE` type in a dialog.

I dont want to add an Image Icon in the `JFrame`.
I am extending my class from `JDialog`. Is it possible to use `MessageType` in my frame?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Method `setAlwaysOnTop(boolean)` belongs to `Window` class. So both classes `JDialog` and `JFrame` inherit this method. You can use `JDialog` marked as `AlwaysOnTop`.

You can use `JOptionPane` to prepare required `JDialog`:

```
JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane("ErrorMsg", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);    
JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog("Failure");
dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: How to close the dialog ? after pressing "OK" the program is still running ..how to dispose it .

Comment: What do you want to do? Do you mean modal dialog (setModal(true))? Or you want to get result of user action on the dialog?

Comment: JDialog dialog = new JOptionPane("ErrorMsg", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE,JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION).createDialog("  Failure");
dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
dialog.setVisible(true);
dialog.dispose();

Comment: Thanks a Lot :) !! the above code is working , optimum solution for my problem ..

Comment: Don't mention it. :) Now you can mark this question as unswered.

Answer (score 3):

you can pass any `JComponent` as `Object` in the conctructor for [JOptionPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html),

in your case is there `null value` - JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(`null`, "ErrorMsg", for example

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(myFrame, 
  "ErrorMsg", "Failure", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: But what does that mean?  I believe mKorbel outlined the best way to get a dialog always on top of a frame.  If the entire application is minimized or another app. takes priority, your app. should surrender the screen space.