# Can I create a Window in Java with no caption buttons?

Tags: java, swing, window, jframe, jwindow

Is it possible to create a Window object of some sort in Java that has a frame and border, but no caption buttons (minimise, restore, close).

Naturally, I can't use the `undecorated` setting. Further, the window needs to:

- Have a platform-rendered border
- Have a titlebar
- Have **no caption buttons**. If need be, I'll take care of disposing the window programmatically.
- Use the default, or `System` Look and Feel

Here is an example:

[image: captionless window]

Comment: look at this thread, it will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665355/how-do-i-remove-the-maximize-and-minimize-buttons-from-a-jframe

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/swing/1.4/w2k_props.html

Comment: or you can also use JWindow instead of JFrame for such example as above. It will not have those 3 usual buttons

Comment: @lebryant the example you posted simply uses a JDialog. A JDialog will still have a close button.

Comment: @lebryant A JWindow by default is completely undecorated, and not resizeable. Is there anything I can do to decorate it?

Comment: @lebryant it will also have no border

Comment: I've provided an example code to customize JFrame buttons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is no.

The longer answer is, probably, but you'll need to investigate a JNI/JNA implementation

Comment: ... and the long and short of it is... it's probably not worth the effort in most cases

Comment: not sure (as you mentioned you are Java1.3 dinosaurus, I'm from Java1.6.09) up to Java1.4 was possible to change DecorationsType without restrictions for Top-Level Containers +1

Answer (score 6):

this is about

1. decent [How to Create Translucent and Shaped Windows](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html)
2. undecorated `JDialog` with [Compound Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html), then you can create similair or nicer Borders as came from Native OS
3. create `JPanel` (or`JLabel#opaque(true)`) with `GradientPaint`
4. or (better `non_focusable` == my view) `JLabel` with prepared `Icon`
5. add to `JPanel` / `JLabel` the [Component Mover / Component Resize](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/) (notice, don't never to mix these two codes together) by @camickr
6. set `Alpha Transparency` for painting in `JPanel` / `JLabel` for great `look and feel`
7. simplest of ways is put there `JMenuBar`

Answer (score 2):

Try this small example. It will remove (not only disable) minimse, maximise and close button from JFrame.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Example {

    public void buildGUI() {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        removeButtons(frame);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        JButton button = new JButton("Exit");
        panel.add(button,new GridBagConstraints());
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setSize(400,300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

    public void removeButtons(Component comp) {
        if(comp instanceof AbstractButton) {
            comp.getParent().remove(comp);
        }
        if (comp instanceof Container) {
            Component[] comps = ((Container)comp).getComponents();
            for(int x=0, y=comps.length; x<y; x++) {
                removeButtons(comps[x]);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                new Example().buildGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a bad attempt. However, the window is not resizeable. Also, a requirement is that it uses the System look and feel. Changing to the system look and feel ruins it. Result: with your example on the left, and the same thing modified to use the default look and feel: http://i.imgur.com/pFSRy.png