# Drag undecorated jDialog

Tags: java, swing, jframe, draggable, jdialog

So, I have a jFrame in which I'm building the main interface window of a chat. This window/jFrame has several buttons , each of which show a jDialog (Which I created previously in Netbeans dragging a jDialog onto the parent(?) jFrame).

My problem is that both windows are set to `undecorated = true` and so I wish to let the user drag and move all windows at will by clicking and dragging a portion of the windows (Which emulate the title bar when not undecorated)

In all the jFrames I have accomplished this by the following code just after `initComponents()`:

```
    final Point point = new Point(0,0);        // Why 'final' and not simply Point point?     
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {  
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {  
            if(!e.isMetaDown()){  
                point.x = e.getX();  
                point.y = e.getY(); 
                System.out.println("Ratón pulsado: " + point.x + "," + point.y);
            }  
        }  
    });

    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {  
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {  
            if(!e.isMetaDown() &&  point.y <= 17){  //Coordinates of title bar, any X and up to 17px from the top border
                Point p = getLocation();  
                setLocation(p.x + e.getX() - point.x, p.y + e.getY() - point.y); 
                System.out.println("Ratón movido: " + (p.x + e.getX() - point.x) + "," + (p.y + e.getY() - point.y));
            }  
        }  
    });
```

However, I don't know how to use this code in the jDialog. When I right click it in the Navigator, and select Customize code, then I can't paste it in there because the whole jFrame stops working. I'm new in this thing of jDialogs children of jFrames, so please help me with some guidelines :) Thanks

Comment: search for component mover, don't forget to upvote author of this(those) answer(s)

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7760896/230513).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, as @mKorbel suggested, I headed to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12278919/can-i-create-a-window-in-java-with-no-caption-buttons/12280616#12280616) where I found a nice class called `ComponentMover` which helped me to do this. I'll need 2 more reputation so I saved the link to get back and upvote when I'm able to do it.

I'll have to ensure it works perfect and exactly in the way I want, but looks great! Thanks!