# How to change default operating system's frame around swing application

Tags: java, swing, substance

For example instead of the default operating system container around the application you could have something custom like this swing project below.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a transparent image on a undecorated frame with a transparent background:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TransparentImageFrame
{
    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JLabel label = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("...") );
        label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
            {
                if (e.getClickCount() == 2)
                {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        });

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Image Frame");
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add( label );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The mouse will only respond to non-opaque pixels in whatever image you use.

Answer (score 4):

The host OS owns the frame decorations, but you can [*Create Translucent and Shaped Windows*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html) and use [`Frame#setUndecorated()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setUndecorated%28boolean%29), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3534673/230513).

Comment: So how can games like elder scrolls create custom frame decorations as well an example like this picture above?

Comment: I don't see any [frame decorations](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10360374/230513) on the example image.