# How to remove Maximize button in swing designer without JDialog?

Tags: java, swing, button, jframe

Is there a way to remove the maximize button and leave the minimize button and close button without using JDialog. I already know you can set resizable to false like this:

```
frame = new JFrame();
frame.setResizable(false);
frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

but I want to just get rid of the button.
Is that possible at all?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a JDialog? See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665355/how-do-i-remove-the-maximize-and-minimize-buttons-from-a-jframe

Comment: Because you cannot have the minimize button, I still want the minimize button and the close button but not the Maximize button

Comment: This can't be done within Java

Comment: You can use JWindow and provide your own controls

Comment: It is possible to remove the Maximize button ( or Minimize or Close ) if your app meets specific OS and Look & Feel conditions.  Are you looking for a cross-platform solution or a specific OS solution? Cross-platform solution is limited to Java (ie Swing) look and feel.  In any case, operating outside of the standard JFrame & JDialog frame control set is not advisable but I understand sometimes there are specific needs.

Comment: Well I was testing on Windows and Linux so Cross-platform solution. And I was trying to do it for looks but if it cannot be done, or if it looks worse than I just wont do it.